# Geometric Interpretations of Sets of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm learning about planes, hyperplanes and lines. I think I have the basics down now:
A hyperplane is when the "surface" is exactly one dimension less than the $\mathbb{R}$. For example, the span $\{(1,0,0) (0,1,0)\}$ forms a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ because there are 2 vectors (1 less than the 3 from the $\mathbb{R}$)

Now if we take a set of vectors $\{(-2, 0, -2, 2), (0, 6, 3, 3), (-1, -1, -1, 2)\}$ this is just three points in $\mathbb{R}^4$ because we didn't put the "span" in front of it.

If we take the same set of vectors $\{(-2, 0, -2, 2), (0, 6, 3, 3), (-1, -1, -1, 2)\}$ and look at the set of all vectors that are orthogonal to this set this is more like having the span situation than the set of points situation since the set of vectors orthogonal to each vector is a plane of some sort. So in this case we end up with 3 hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

But then if we consider all three hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ the set that is orthogonal to all three vectors at once must be where the hyperplanes cross which should be a line?

Where has my logic gone wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think your logic has gone wrong?

Comment: I find that thinking in terms of [*codimension*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codimension) rather than dimension of subspaces is quite useful. Count down from the top dimension according to the number of linear equations when subspaces intersect transversely. Hyperplanes are simply subspaces of codimension $1$ in this language, and the intersection of two (non-parallel) hyperplanes has codimension $2$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The set of vectors orthogonal to each one of those three vectors is a hyperplane.

The set of vectors orthogonal to all three is the intersection of those three hyperplanes. It's a one dimensional subspace (in this case).

There is a way in which the span enters the picture.
Another way to look at this is that the set of vectors orthogonal to all the vectors in a given set $S$ (of any size) is the set of vectors orthogonal to the span of $S$. Its dimension (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is $n - $ the dimension of the span of $S$.

Try drawing some pictures when $n=3$.